# How to download a whole ftp directory to user client through a web application

Tags: java, ftp

The web application is developed with Java/Jsp. One thing I want to do is download a directory from FTP to one user client pc. Since there are at least 700MB of files to be transferd in the directory, and the FTP download speed is sometimes very slow. When I was using an ativex to do the downloading, the web page just got stuck for a very long time. And when the downloading is done, the session times out. So how can I solve the downloading and the timeout things?

Comment: currently how  you are implemented?

Comment: I developed an simple ActiveX control which was written by vc++.But when I called ActiveX methods in Jsp,since the downloading was running,the page got stuck.During this time,the page displayed nothing .Do I need to developed something like a progress bar?

Comment: It is always better to dsign a progress bar and notify the user

Answer (score 2):

you can take reference from here
`http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/how-to-download-a-complete-folder-from-a-ftp-server`
It worked for me